# Can a website detect extensions that are installed using Developed Mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, google-chrome-app

In my case, I am using an extension that is prohibited by the website. I had downloaded the extension as a Zip file from the Chrome store and edited it in Notepad++, changed its name, and other things that can help in identifying the extension. But the code is the same, and permissions to access the site are the same, and then installed in developer mode on chrome. Can that website detect that I am using it?

Manifest.json file code:

```
{
"author": "Johnny Bravo",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png",
    "default_popup": "/popup.html",
    "name": "Gaming Options"
},
"description": "DEVELOPED SPECIALLY FOR GAMERS WHO SAY: I LOVE GAMING!  I LOVE GAMING!  I LOVE GAMING!",
"icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Gaming Options",
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://quiz.vu.edu.pk/QuizQuestion.aspx*",
        "https://quiz.vu.edu.pk/QuizQuestion.aspx*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "popup.js",
        "siteJsCode.js",
        "copy_search.js",
        "jquery.min.js"
    ]
}],
"permissions": ["http://quiz.vu.edu.pk/*", "https://quiz.vu.edu.pk/*"],
"version": "1.1"}
```

Comment: It depends on what exactly the extension does in its content scripts and whether it exposes its resources to the web.

Comment: @wOxxOm, They must need the extension ID???
I installed the extension using developer mode and its Extension ID is not the same as the original extension, so they don't know the extension ID of my modified extension.

Comment: This question is not closed, I haven't found my answer yet, so please whoever sees this please answer this question or add a comment if know about this. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what exactly the extension does in its content scripts and whether it exposes its resources to the web. You need to investigate the source code of your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm, can I share the manifest.json file of my extension, it has about 25 lines of code and you can tell me if it exposes its resources.

Comment: manifest.json doesn't expose any resources but the extension may do it in its content scripts. You need to investigate the source code of your extension.